# Can I concurrently pull my git repos without gnu parallel?

Tags: gnu-parallel

On my home machine, I use the script `gitpull.sh` to concurrently pull all the changes to the git repos under a given directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

find $1 -name ".git" | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' | parallel git -C {} pull origin master
```

My problem is that `parallel` is not installed on my work computer. Is it possible to alter my script without the use of `parallel`?

Comment: do you have GNU `findutils` on your work computer? or something else that provides `xargs`?   if so, you can write a version of your gitpull.sh that pipes the sed output into a shell function that does something like `xargs -I{} git pull -C {} origin master &`.

Comment: Is the reason why you do not have GNU Parallel covered by http://oletange.blogspot.com/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html? If not, please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of parallel you could use xargs with the -P flag. Something like:

```
find $1 -name ".git" | sed -r 's|/[^/]+$||' | xargs -I {} -n 1 -P 0 git -C {} pull origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this tool [Git-Plus](https://github.com/tkrajina/git-plus) to concurrently pull all the changes to the git repos under a given directory. Use this command

```
$ git multi pull
```

You can easily install it and use it .

Comment: This does not seem to execute in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using only bash, readlink, and find:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -d '' -r g ; do 
  dir="$(readlink -f "$g/..")"
  git pull -C "$dir" origin master &
done < <(find "$@" -name '.git' -print0)
```

You can make it run a bit faster with careful use of find's `-maxdepth` option.  e.g. if you know that all `.git` directories are going to be found **only** in the top-level sub-directories of the current directory, `-maxdepth 3` will stop it recursing into any lower sub-directories.

I've used `"$@"` with the `find` command rather than the unquoted `$1` you used so that not only is a directory argument optional, you can use multiple directory args and/or add whatever find options you might need to the command line.

If the version of `find` on your work computer doesn't do `-print0`, you can use `\n` as the input separator, but the script will break if any directory names contain a newline (which is uncommon but perfectly valid).

```bash
while IFS= read -r g ; do 
  dir="$(readlink -f "$g/..")"
  git pull -C "$dir" origin master &
done < <(find "$@" -name '.git')
```